# Android: Make visible to particular widgets in the row of ListView on Click of Clickable span

Tags: android, listview

Here I have few widgets in a row of `ListView`.

I need to get right position of the widgets and manage their visibilities inside adapter. Currently it makes visible to `last item` of the `ListView`.

I'm using `getTag()` and `setTag()` also here but its not getting success.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clist_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.requestion_layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.requestion_layout);
holder.submitAnswerBtn = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submit_answer_btn);
holder.questionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_title);
 //these are the widgets 
    holder.requestion_layout.setTag(position);
    holder.submitAnswerBtn.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


//trying to change visibility on click of Clickable Span 
 Spannable main_words = new SpannableString(items.get(position).getAnswer() + "");
        int color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.light_black);
        main_words.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color1), 0, main_words.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        int color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.tab_green);
        Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString("Reply");
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                //Toast.makeText(DummyActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Integer position_clicked = (Integer) v.getTag();
           //Widgets are not getting their positions here
                holder.requestion_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.submitAnswerBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
        wordTwo.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, wordTwo.toString().length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color2), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        wordTwo.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        CharSequence concat = TextUtils.concat(main_words, " ", wordTwo);
        holder.answerValue.setText(concat);
        holder.answerValue.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        holder.answerValue.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.answerValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.answerTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
return convertView;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this issue you must use an `arrayList` and set a flag there with positions as

```
//Define arraylist globally
 private List<Boolean> requestionVisibleState;

//set a default value in constructor of adapter
 this.requestionVisibleState = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[getCount()]));
    Collections.fill(this.requestionVisibleState, false);

//In getView after completing if else statement
 if (requestionVisibleState.get(position)) {
        holder.submitAnswerBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.requestion_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
//And in `onClick` of your ClicableSpan
                    if (requestionVisibleState.get(position)) {
                        requestionVisibleState.set(position, false);
                    } else {
                        requestionVisibleState.set(position, true);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope it'll work for you.